# Submit the form using JavaScript showing the please wait message not functioning

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, in a form submit event I wanted to show please wait for a message when clicking the submit button.

There also I have added `required` attributes for the mandatory fields.

So I modified the code as follows. Then it checks the `required` fields are filled before submitting.

But when this happens it doesn't show the please wait for meassage.

Even if all fields are filled, it's also submitting the data without showing the `Please wait for`  message.

This is the example I got from the internet. https://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/displaying-a-wait-message-on-an-mvc-page

This is my customized code

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-10">
  <input type="submit" value="Register Customer" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return DisplayProgressMessage();" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function DisplayProgressMessage(ctl, msg) {
  //document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = 'none',
  $('my-form').on('submit', CheckRequired);
  $(ctl).prop("disabled", true);
  $(ctl).text(msg);
  $(".submit-progress").removeClass("hidden");
  $("body").addClass("submit-progress-bg");

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it doing this change

```
  let allAreFilled = true;
 document.getElementById("my-form").querySelectorAll("[required]").forEach(function (i) {
   if (!allAreFilled) return;
   if (!i.value) {
     allAreFilled = false;
     return;
   }
 })
 if (!allAreFilled) {

 } else {
   $(ctl).prop("disabled", true);
   $(ctl).text(msg);
   $(".submit-progress").removeClass("hidden");
   $("body").addClass("submit-progress-bg");
   document.getElementById("my-form").submit();
 }
```